# How to have type-safety dependent on a number? (like generics are dependent on a Type)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-safety

I want a `Type` that is "for" a certain number, and another `Type` for another number. But I don't want to have to manually define a `Type` for each number like `Level1024` and `Level1000`. I want it to be simple to instantiate an instance of the `Level` class for each number, like we can do with generics where we can create a `Level<string>` and a `Level<int>` without needing to define a separate `Level` for each of them.

Here's the idea:

```
Level<1024> topPlayerOf1K;
Level<1000> Abe = new Level<1000>();
topPlayerOf1K = Abe; //This should show a squiggly line in Visual Studio.
```

How can I achieve that or something like that?

Comment: Make a non generic base class and let your generic class derive from it.

Comment: What's preventing you from adding get-only property and instantiate in the .ctor: `new Level(1024)`.

Comment: @Oliver Can you elaborate? How would that give me type-safety?

Comment: @MetroSmurf How would that achieve type-safety (see that last line in the code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers literals are not considered types in C# like they are in TypeScript, and cannot be used as generic parameters like template parameters in C++.

At the minimum you would have to create types for each of the number literals you want to use. The approach could look like this:

```cs
interface IConstantInt { int Value { get; } }

class ConstantInt1000 : IConstantInt { public int Value => 1000; }
class ConstantInt1024 : IConstantInt { public int Value => 1024; }

class Level<TConstantInt> where TConstantInt : IConstantInt { }

var level1000 = new Level<ConstantInt1000>();
var level1024 = new Level<ConstantInt1024>();
```

It would be good to autogenerate this code if you're going to have many of those. This is not a great solution, but without knowing more about your program and what kind of errors you're trying to prevent, in the abstract, that's a way that you could encode number literals in the type system.

Edit: here's one way that you could access the value inside the class:

```cs
class Level<TConstantInt> where TConstantInt : IConstantInt 
{
    readonly int _intValue;

    public Level(TConstantInt constantInt) => 
        _intValue = constantInt.Value;
}

class Level
{
    // Optional utility factory method, helps with type inference
    public static Level<TConstantInt> Create<TConstantInt>(TConstantInt constantInt) 
        where TConstantInt : IConstantInt =>
        new(constantInt);
}

// Now creation looks like this:

var level1000 = Level.Create(new ConstantInt1000());
var level1024 = Level.Create(new ConstantInt1024());
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a creative solution.

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to get the `int` itself from within the `Level` class, but this is still the best I have. So I'm accepting this answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I added an example for that.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated.